# Add marker to multiple layer groups

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have created a map with leafletjs using StyledLayerControl and markercluster:
https://www.wiva.at/v2/basemap-kartentest/
Each marker represents a research project that fits in one category (=layergroup).
Unfortunately I have some projects that fall into three categories (like the very south one near the city LEIBNITZ close to GRAZ). So far this one project is represented as three markers, and I got the feedback this confuses especially in the spiderfied view.
I've come across an issue, when assigning my marker to a variable and then adding the variable to multiple layergroups that unselecting one layergroup makes the marker disappear in the other layer groups as well.
So is there any chance to represent such a project as ONE marker but appearing in multiple layer groups?

If the link above is not sufficient I can add my code (but I'm afraid it's kind of messy).

Thanks for any hint.

EDIT:

So far I add my marker simply like that:

```
    //Green Industry projects
    //new (running) projects
    var industry_new = new L.LayerGroup();

    //Renewable Gasfield, laufend, Wiva, ONLINE
    L.marker([46.753278, 15.586361], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>Renewable Gasfield</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> Energie Steiermark<br /><b>Standort:</b> Gabersdorf<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Industrie<br /><b>Status:</b> laufend<br /><p>Ganzheitlicher Power-to-Gas Ansatz, bei dem aus erneuerbarem Strom durch Elektrolyse grüner Wasserstoff erzeugt wird und eine zweistufige katalytische Methanisierung im großen Maßstab für eine nachhaltige Energieversorgung in den Bereichen Energie, Mobilität und Industrie vereint.</p><a href='https://www.wiva.at/v2/portfolio-item/renewable-gasfield/'>Details...</a>");

    //HyTechbasis 4 WIVA, laufend, Wiva, ONLINE
    L.marker([48.155278, 14.048056], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>HyTechbasis 4 WIVA</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> FRONIUS INTERNATIONAL GmbH<br /><b>Standort:</b> Thalheim<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Industrie<br /><b>Status:</b> laufend<br /><p>Hydrogen Technology Basis for WIVA</p><a href='https://www.wiva.at/v2/portfolio-item/hytechbasis-4-wiva-hydrogen-technology-basis-for-wiva/'>Details...</a>");

    //Co2EXIDE WIVA, laufend, Wiva, ONLINE
    L.marker([48.33826938809515, 14.317320611066839], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>CO2EXIDE</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> (österreichischer Partner) Energieinstitut an der JKU Linz<br /><b>Standort:</b> AGH Krakau Demo-Anlage<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Industrie<br /><b>Status:</b> laufend<br /><p>CO2-basierte Elektrosynthese von Ethylen Oxiden</p><a href='http://www.co2exide.eu/'>Details...</a>");
        
    //CORALIS WIVA, laufend, Wiva, ONLINE
    L.marker([48.288029, 14.324497], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>CORALIS</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> Fundación CIRCE / Öst. Partner: Energieinstitut an der JKU Linz<br /><b>Standort:</b> Linz<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Industrie<br /><b>Status:</b> laufend<br /><p>Erfahrungen im Bereich der Industriesymbiose zusammenstellen</p><a href='https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/958337'>Details...</a>");

    //UpHY, laufend, Wiva, ONLINE
    L.marker([48.14735053624901, 16.492216234765525], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>UpHy I</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> OMV<br /><b>Standort:</b> Wien<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Mobilität<br /><b>Status:</b> laufend<br /><p>Im Project UpHy I wird die Basis für die Demonstration der Wertschöpfungskette für die grüne H2- Mobilität von der Produktion in einer Elektrolyse über die Logistik bis zur 350 bar Betankungsinfrastruktur für eine kommerziell betriebene Buslinie mit Brennstoffzellenantrieb entwickelt.</p><a href='https://www.wiva.at/v2/portfolio-item/uphy-upscaling-of-green-hydrogen-for-mobility-and-industry/'>Details...</a>");

    //Underground Sun.Conversion, laufend, Wiva-Netzwerk
    L.marker([48.028889, 13.691944], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(industry_new).bindPopup("<p><span style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold; color:#0099b8;'>Underground Sun.Conversion</span></p><b>Projektleitung:</b> RAG Austria AG<br /><b>Standort:</b> Pilsbach<br /><b>Kategorie:</b> Grüne Industrie<br /><b>Status:</b> abgeschlossen<br /><p>Chemical storage of renewable energy in porous subsurface reservoirs with exemplary testbed</p><a href='https://www.underground-sun-conversion.at/'>Details...</a>");
```

I do that for each layer group. Probably this is not the best way, but for me as a java and leaflet beginner the easiest way and I was just very happy everything worked out so far ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that is an unresolved UX issue. The main issue is that in some use cases, you want an OR filter (sounds like it would be your case, since your Markers are duplicated in each group where they fit the associated category); and in others, you want an AND filter...

So if you want to populate your map with all Markers that fit *at least* one selected category (i.e. implement an OR filter), a possible solution could be to use "dummy" empty Layer Groups for your selection control, clear and re-populate the map with relevant Markers whenever the user selection changes.

For example, if you have the map "overlayadd/remove" events:

```js
// "Dummy" layers to be used in selection control
const dummy1 = L.layerGroup();
const dummy2 = L.layerGroup();

// Actual categories with possibly common Markers
const category1 = L.layerGroup([markerA, markerB]);
const category2 = L.layerGroup([markerA, markerC]);

// Intermediate group to easily clear map content
const content = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

map.on("overlayadd overlayremove", () => {
  // Step 1: remove all content
  content.clearLayers();
  // Step 2: re-add layers that fit at least one selection
  if (map.hasLayer(dummy1)) {
    category1.addTo(content)
  }
  if (map.hasLayer(dummy2)) {
    category2.addTo(content)
  }
  // etc.
});
```

In case you use Leaflet.markercluster, you can simply use it as the `content` variable in above snippet.

You also have to create only 1 Marker per project, no longer duplicate them for each category. In normal use cases, this should be avoided, but here we specifically handle this case. For example if Marker A matches categories 1 and 2, you can do:

```
L.marker(latLngA).addTo(category1).addTo(category2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed response, I will try this!

Comment: So, I tried it, but following your example for the case that `category1` is selected in the control `markerA` and `markerB` are shown on the map. if then `category2` is selected too, the following happens: all layers from `content` removed, `category1` re-added (`markerA`, and `markerB`), `category2` re-added -> which unfortunately adds all marker of `category2` (also `markerA` again...) that doesn't help at all...
My thoughts:  I have to make a `FOR` loop through all markers in `category2` to check if one is already in `content`
If so, how can I access these markers or create such a loop?

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are describing above vs what you are trying to achieve: if I understand correctly, in your category2 you also have a Marker for project A, but which is actually a different object than the one for the same project in category1? Or are your 2x MarkerA the actual same JavaScript object already?

Comment: I have it like that now:
`const category1 = new L.LayerGroup();
//markerA
L.marker([46.753278, 15.586361], {icon: mixIcon} ).addTo(category1).bindPopup("Description MarkerA");
//markerB
L.marker([41.123745, 13.096532], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(category2).bindPopup("MarkerB");

const category2 = new L.LayerGroup();
//markerA
L.marker([46.753278, 15.586361], {icon: mixIcon} ).addTo(category2).bindPopup("MarkerA");
//markerC
L.marker([48.155278, 14.048056], {icon: industryIcon} ).addTo(category2).bindPopup("MarkerC.");`
I'm afraid they are two different objects? (I'mJava beginner)

Comment: Sorry for the code mess, didn't got the paragraphs right...

Comment: You can _edit_ your question. Within the body of the question, code is properly formatted. Whereas in comments it remains inline.

Comment: Indeed from your above code, you create separate Marker objects for the same coordinates,  representing the same project I suppose. If you can share how your initial data looks like and how you use it to build those Markers in each category, we could  figure out a solution.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks again for your support!

Comment: Added a code sample to explain that you can add the same Marker object to several Layer Groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that!

Comment: It worked that way! Thank you very much!!! https://www.wiva.at/v2/projekte-3/

Comment: Thank you for your nice feedback! Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you. It also signals to others that your issue is solved.

Comment: I've worked this out on a slightly different way on [Having Leaflet markers visible in more than one layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644888/having-leaflet-markers-visible-in-more-than-one-layer)