# React Leaflet with grouped layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

Hi I'm trying to add multiple layers to a Leaflet map using the layer control. I want to filter layers on the map where there is a main selection of the data set and from there is displays the data based on that set.

Image of control box:

[image: Image of control box]

I understand how to add layers to the map and selecting based on it. But I want to show layers based on the exclusive controls and then the filters to show filtered layers.

Where selecting colorado and males would be like a query where it asks for males in Colorado

```js
var groupedOverlays = {
  "states": {
    "Colorado" : groups.colorado,
    "New Mexico" : groups.newMexico,
    "Arizona" : groups.arizona
  },
  "GenderAndAges": {
    "Male": groups.,
    "Female": groups.,
    "Under 18 years old": groups.,
    "18 to 55 years old": groups.

  }
}; 

var options = {

  exclusiveGroups: ["states"],
  groupCheckboxes: false
};
```

Comment: The built-in leaflet layerControl is not meant for that - meaning its not that advanced.  Its really meant for simply adding and removing layers to and from the map.  However this is a very interesting idea.  Can we get some more information?  What is the data source for this layer?  How are you building your queries?  I'm sure you can build a custom widget that has the look and behavior you want.

Comment: Also, are you using react-leaflet specifically?  Or just react and leaflet?

Comment: Right now, I have several .json files that would go to each of the possible combinations. Like male, state, and age

Comment: Meaning I have a json file for each possibility. The 3 states, 2 genders, and 3 age groups.

Comment: @SethLutske I'm using React and Leaflet

Comment: So you have 3 * 3 * 2 = 18 json files?

Comment: Yeah I have 18 Json files for it

Comment: This really shouldn't be too hard, you just need to use the widget to filter what JSON is being used.  Are these large files? Could you create a codesandbox to play with that has a similar setup?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a similar use case as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66412288/5108796, except that you want the AND filter option.

Therefore building on that case, and assuming first that you can load all your data, a possible solution would be to:

- Assign your Layers to all groups they fit into (e.g. a male in Colorado would be a single Layer, added into both "males" and "Colorado" arrays or LayerGroups)
- Use dummy LayerGroups in your LayersControl, as done in the above linked answer
- Whenever the selection changes, add all matching arrays/LayerGroups and remove all non-matching ones, so that you leave only the Layers that fit into the AND combined filters

For example, if you have the map "overlayadd/remove" events:

```js
// "Dummy" layers to be used in selection control
const dummyColorado = L.layerGroup();
const dummyArizona = L.layerGroup();
const dummyMales = L.layerGroup();
const dummyFemales = L.layerGroup();

// Actual categories with possibly common Markers
const colorado = [maleColoradoA, femaleColoradoB];
const arizona = [maleArizonaC, femaleArizonaD];
const males = [maleColoradoA, maleArizonaC];
const females = [femaleColoradoB, femaleArizonaD];

// Intermediate group to work outside map to avoid potential performance issue
const content = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

map.on("overlayadd overlayremove", () => {
  // Step 1: remove all content
  content.remove();
  content.clearLayers();
  // Step 2: re-add Layers that fit at least one selection in 1 dimension (e.g. loop over the areas)
  if (map.hasLayer(dummyColorado)) {
    colorado.forEach(marker => marker.addTo(content));
  }
  if (map.hasLayer(dummyArizona)) {
    arizona.forEach(marker => marker.addTo(content));
  }
  // Step 3: remove all Layers that do not match selection in all other dimensions (here gender, age, etc.)
  if (!map.hasLayer(dummyMales)) {
    males.forEach(marker => content.removeLayer(marker));
  }
  // etc.
  // Step 4: re-add content on map
  content.addTo(map);
});
```

Now if you have to keep your data as external individual files (1 per possible combination) and load them dynamically only on user selection, you can adapt the above technique:

```js
// "Dummy" layers to be used in selection control
const dummyColorado = L.layerGroup();
const dummyArizona = L.layerGroup();
const dummyMales = L.layerGroup();
const dummyFemales = L.layerGroup();

// Intermediate group to easily reset content
const content = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

map.on("overlayadd overlayremove", () => {
  // Step 1: remove all content
  content.clearLayers();
  // Step 2: re-add data that fit combinations 
  if (map.hasLayer(dummyColorado) && map.hasLayer(dummyMales)) {
    // Load the data file for males in Colorado combination
    // and add into the content LayerGroup
    // e.g. with jQuery and assuming GeoJSON data:
    $.getJSON("pathToMaleColorado.json", (data) => {
      L.geoJSON(data).addTo(content);
    });
  }
  // etc.
});
```