# Leaflet marker on multiple layer

Tags: leaflet

I have created a leaflet map to display some data and now want to add a 'filter' to my map. I am using the grouped layer control plugin and have an issue which I cannot quite solve. For example I have 2 (or more) conditions which decide whether or not to show the marker and right now it works more like a OR filter, but i want a AND filter so that both (or more) conditions need to be checked in the overlay in order for the marker to be shown. If you have an idea or know about a post which already covered this issue, please let me know.

Code:

```
var berlin_1 = L.marker([52.48937,13.50341]).addTo(map);

//grouping

var A = L.layerGroup([berlin_1]);
var B = L.layerGroup ([berlin_1]);

//overlay

var groupedOverlays = {
 "(headline1)": {
 "condition 1": A,},
 "(headline2)":{
   "condition 2": B}};
 
  L.control.groupedLayers(null, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698913/react-leaflet-with-grouped-layers?noredirect=1&lq=1