# Having Leaflet markers visible in more than one layer

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, layer, marker

I want some of my Leaflet markers visible in more than one layer on my Openstreetmap map.

By example: London is harbor and is also a capital city.
So I want to see the London marker when I select only the layer 'harbors' or the layer 'capital cities'.

But the normal behaviour of Leaflet markers and layers seems to be that London only shows up when both layers 'harbors' and 'capital cities' are selected.

How to achieve to show up the London marker if just one of the two layers is selected?

Code:

```
var harbor  = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var capital = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
      
var marker1 = L.marker([51.5, 0]);
marker1.addTo(harbor);
marker1.addTo(capital);

var overlays = { "Capital": capital, "Harbor": harbor}; 
L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: It really depends on how you have structured your harbors, capitals and London layers. If you can share how you have done it which makes London visible only if the 2 harbors and capitals have been selected, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Cheat. Have two overlapping markers, one for the harbor and one for the city.

Comment: @ghybs I've added code to my question.

Comment: Have a look if the response to this similar question works for you:
[Add marker to multiple layer groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66391786/1391631)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link @Tordanik gave, was helpfull.
Adding this code does the job:

```
map.on("overlayremove", function(o) {
        
  if (map.hasLayer(capital)) {
    map.removeLayer(capital);
    map.addLayer(capital);
  }
        
  if (map.hasLayer(harbor)) {
    map.removeLayer(harbor);
    map.addLayer(harbor);
  }
        
});
```

Steps taken after an ovelayremove-click:

1. Test each layers if it is active
2. Remove this layer
3. Place this layer with his markers back
   Result: all the markers in this layer are visible again.

Comment: I've noticed that it becomes somewhat slow with more than three of four layers with markers.